# Integrate by changing order of integration

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm trying to evaluate this integral:

$$ \int_{x^2}^{x} \int_0^1 \frac{x}{y} e^y dx dy $$

If I evaluate this straightforwardly, I end up with the integral

$$ \frac{1}{2} \int_{x^2}^{x} \frac{e^y}{y} dy $$

Which cannot be expressed as an elementary function.

I think I need to change the order of integration. The new bounds are then $ \sqrt{y} \leq x \leq y$ and $ 0 \leq y \leq 1 $ (I think), which gives this integral

$$ \int_\sqrt{y}^{y} \int_0^1 \frac{x}{y} e^y dy dx $$

And I still have to deal with the $ \int_0^1 \frac{e^y}{y} dy $. I'm told this can be solved in terms of elementary functions, but I'm stumped. Can someone point out my mistake?

*edit*: The exact wording of the question is to evaluate the following integral where $R$ is bounded by $ 0 \leq x \leq 1, x^2 \leq y \leq x$

$$ \iint_R \frac{x}{y}e^y dx dy $$

Comment: The integral that you wrote has outer limits that depend on $x$. Are you sure you didn't mean $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{1}\int_{x}^{x^2}\dfrac{x}{y}e^y\,dy\,dx$?

Comment: Also, are you sure the limits aren't supposed to be $\int_{x^2}^x$? You wrote that on the second line, and that makes more sense as $x_2\leq x$ on $[0,1]$.

Comment: @JimmyK4542: See my edit, maybe that's where my mistake is

Comment: @kccu: you're right, thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initial integral is set up incorrectly. As noted in the comments, you cannot have outer limits that depend on a variable. Using the given bounds, you can write the integral as
$$\int_0^1\int_{x^2}^x\frac{x}{y}e^y\ dy\ dx.$$
As you noted, you'll want to change the order of integration. You are correct that the constant bounds for $y$ are $0\leq y \leq 1$. The bound $x^2 \leq y \leq x$ tells you that $\sqrt{y} \geq \sqrt{x^2}=|x|=x$ (as the region $R$ is in the first quadrant where $x$ and $y$ are nonnegative). You also have $y \leq x$, so the bound for $x$ in terms of $y$ becomes $y\leq x \leq \sqrt{y}$. The integral then becomes
$$\int_0^1\int_{\sqrt{y}}^y\frac{x}{y}e^y \ dx \ dy.$$
You should be able to solve the integral from there.

Comment: Thanks! The answer comes quickly once the problem is set up correctly...